# How do I simplify if statements in python using and?

Tags: python

In my code, I am trying to do something like this:

```py
if a=="1" and b=="1":
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Is it possible to simplify that so that I can check a and b in one part?

I've tried some stuff, like

```py
if a and b == "1":
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

but it just returns true when `b == 1`, and a == anything

Now resolved, but can't take it out of review.

Comment: It's just the matter of writing that is not really necessary. And if you just need to do that two comparations, it's already optimal one.

Comment: you can do `if all(i=='1' for i in [a, b]): print(True)`, though first one is clean and optimum

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Those questions both look different to me. Which of their answers answer this one? I'd expect something like svfat's answer.

Comment: I've added an appropriate duplicate: `if a == b == "1"`.

Comment: @deceze I think that should be the only one. The  first two look completely off-topic and the fourth merely addresses their "a == anything" misconception and also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @deceze thank you, that works, i can go to sleep now

Comment: @KellyBundy I used those targets because you never know what other tests OP might have. That being said you have a gold badge, you can edit the dupe target list to your liking.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Yeah, I just don't overrule others (especially gold ones) without understanding their reasons.